# How to set the environment for Grunt?

Tags: gruntjs, config, development-environment, production-environment, gruntfile

I defined a task section of my `Gruntfile.js` for two environments -- `development` and `production`. But I don't understand, how Grunt decides, wheter to use which environment section.

**`Gruntfile.js`**

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    less: {
      development: {
        options: {
          paths: ["public/css"]
        },
        files: {
          "public/css/style.css": "public/css/style.less"
        }
      },
      production: {
        options: {
          paths: ["public/css"],
          plugins: [
          ],
          modifyVars: {
          }
        },
        files: {
          "public/css/style.css": "public/css/style.less"
        }
      }
    },
    watch: {
      css: {
        files: 'public/css/*.less',
        tasks: ['less'],
        options: {
          livereload: true,
        },
      },
    }
  });

  // Load the plugin that provides the "less" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-less');
  // Load the plugin that provides the "watch" task.
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['less', 'watch']);

};
```

How to let Grunt know, which environment is currently active?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To alternate I suggest you to create a `development` task and run it with `grunt development`

```
// Default task(s).
grunt.registerTask('default', ['less:production', 'watch']);

// Development task
grunt.registerTask('development', ['less:development', 'watch']);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It works. Is it also possible to get the environment information from a separate file? My idea is to save this information in a non-versioned file, in order to not have to think every time, in which environment I'm currently executing the command.

Comment: In case of LESS (but maybe it's possible for every module, I didn't test it) the call `grunt less:development` works as well. If you know, wheter it works for every task, feel free to extend your answer with this information.

Comment: hi @automatix, that's a bit ahead of the question scope. I suggest you to create another question with these info, I guess other people might find it useful either. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two different grunt files one for development environment and one for production (for instance `gruntfile.dev.js` and `gruntfile.prod.js`) and specify which file should be considered as corresponding `grunfile` by specifying file name in your npm grunt command like this

```
grunt --gruntfile gruntfile.prod.js
```

Remember you can define two aliases for your dev and prod grunt commands
see below

```
"scripts": 
 {
    "build:prod": "grunt --gruntfile gruntfile.prod.js",
    "build:dev": "grunt --gruntfile gruntfile.dev.js",
 }
```

so, by typing `npm run build:prod` the prod gruntfile will be run and by typing `npm run build:dev` dev gruntfile will be run.

By doing so you have more flexibility and it becomes easier to maintain changes associated to your grunt configuration